# UP xtreme i12 realtime Preempt-RT kernel version

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04, preempt-rt

I am building a real time Ubuntu kernel for 20.04 LTS. The kernel version is intel-iotg-5.15.0-1036.41. I tried to build RT kernel by patching it with RT patch, v5.15.125-rt66 and v5.15.70-rt50. But the compile had errors and ... after building the kernel, when the PC turns on, PC said OUT of MEMORY. Is there the right kernel version for intel-iotg-5.15.0-1036.41 or 5.15.0-1016.21?

I built kernel as follows.
First I downloaded a 5.15.origin, and 5.15.0-1036.diff.
After unzip 5.15.origin, I patched using `patch -p1 < 5.15.0-1036.diff`.
And then, I patched kernel using `patch -p1 < rt.patch`.
`cp /boot/config .config`. Then, `make menuconfig`.
I set the config_preempt_rt and CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL, CONFIG_HZ_1000 CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE.
`make -j 16 deb-pkg`. But it was not working.